# React Native flexDirection animation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation

I am trying to to an animation which basically changes `flexDirection` of a view. Check the code

```
state = {
        fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),
        flex_direction_anim: new Animated.Value("column")
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.timing(
            this.state.fadeAnim,
            {
                toValue: 1,                   
                duration: 2000
            }
        ).start();

        setTimeout(() => {
            Animated.timing(
                this.state.flex_direction_anim, {
                    toValue: "row",
                    duration: 2000
                }
            )
        }, 5000)
    }
```

In above code i have two animations set, fade animation is working fine, but the other animation just throws following error.

[image]

I am not sure what i am doing wrong here, may be this kind of animation is not supported in React-Native.

I have also used `react-native-animatable` library, and also opened an issue [here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-animatable/issues/222)

Any documentation or lead will be very helpful, 
Thanks

Comment: Hey! First of all, `toValue` accepts integers, so doing `toValue: "row"` will cause errors. Furthermore I think this tutorial is exactly what you're looking for. I'm not going to put it in the answers because I can't take credit for it. https://tutorialscapital.com/react-native-dynamically-change-flex-direction-layout-using-layout-animation/

Comment: @Harrison thanks for your comment, this have solved my 25% of the problem. Thank u for guidance. :)